# SQL server agent is stopped with error message

Tags: sql-server, server, agent

I've installed SQL server 2017 but the SQL server agent is stopped since installation and all attempts to restart it keeps giving error message:

> the SQL server agent (SQLEXPRESS) service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stops automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

Comment: What edition did you install? Express does not support the Agent.

Comment: For reasons best known only to Microsoft, they *install* an Agent instance for Express but it *cannot run*. You cannot use Agent.

Comment: What can I do to it. I want to be sure if it doesn't affect the operation of my SQL server

Comment: It won't. As stated above, Express doesn't support Agent. It not running is a design feature.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate your comment.